# NullPointerException trying to call a method with correct return type

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Why would this line give me a NullPointerException?

```
List<Comment> commentList = commentDAO.getComments();
```

The getComments() method does indeed return a List, but when I step through the code in Eclipse, the method doesn't even get called.

Comment: if you get NullPointerException on this line and getComments() method is not called, then `commentDAO == null`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only possibility is that commentDAO is null

Comment: Well, it's not the _only_ possibility. Sunspots, cosmic rays, prankster gods, buggy software and so on. But it _is_ the most likely, by a long shot, so +1 :-)